# Getting the right values from the dictionary without duplication

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to match a random amount of employee records to an auditor. so I made a dictionary, the key being the name of the auditors and the values being the list of the employees' names. However, as the result of this, the dictionary values become cumulative and make duplicates of themselves as iteration for auditor's name(dictionary key) goes on. How can I eliminate the duplication of the values??
(audlst is the list of auditors and Empnamelst is the list of the employees and the amount of random employee records that will be assigned to the auditor is determined by user input as empunderaud, the values(employee names) are series taken from a dataframe)

Code:

```
        empunderaud=input('How many records will be assigned to each auditor?')
        empunderaud=int(empunderaud)
        print('Record successfully assigned to auditors')
        #take the emp names only from Mydf
        Empnamelst=Mydf.iloc[:,0] 
        #assign emps to audnames
        assigndict={}
        for audname in audlst:
                print("\nRecords assigned to",audname,': ' )
                rndemp=Empnamelst.sample(empunderaud)
                assigndict[audname]=rndemp

                print(assigndict.values())
```

result:

```
How many records will be assigned to each auditor?2
Record successfully assigned to auditors

Records assigned to ann : 
dict_values([302    Carr, Claudia  N
67      Gonzalez, Maria
Name: Employee_Name, dtype: object])

Records assigned to iron : 
dict_values([302    Carr, Claudia  N
67      Gonzalez, Maria
Name: Employee_Name, dtype: object, 49            Rogers, Ivan
87    Wallace, Courtney  E
Name: Employee_Name, dtype: object])

Records assigned to jin : 
dict_values([302    Carr, Claudia  N
67      Gonzalez, Maria
Name: Employee_Name, dtype: object, 49            Rogers, Ivan
87    Wallace, Courtney  E
Name: Employee_Name, dtype: object, 241         Wolk, Hang  T
235    Winthrop, Jordan  
Name: Employee_Name, dtype: object])
```

Comment: Why not create a list of employee names and use random library sample method to draw employees for each auditor?

Answer (score 0):

To use the random sample method.
create list of auditors and a list of employees.

```
emps = ['EMP_3201', 'EMP_4617', 'EMP_4332', 'EMP_3999', 'EMP_1386', 'EMP_3357', 'EMP_3584',
        'EMP_4698', 'EMP_1484', 'EMP_4268', 'EMP_5368', 'EMP_1969', 'EMP_3398', 'EMP_1874']
auditors = ['auditor_A', 'auditor_B', 'auditor_C', 'auditor_D']  

from random import sample
sample_size = 3
audits =  dict()
for a in auditors:
    ae = sample(emps, sample_size)
    # to ensure no duplicate audits
    for e in ae:
        emps.remove(e)
    audits[a] = ae
print (audits)
```

Produces a dict where the auditor is the key and the employees to audit are the values as shown below:

```
{'auditor_A': ['EMP_4617', 'EMP_3357', 'EMP_1484'], 'auditor_B': ['EMP_3201', 'EMP_5368', 'EMP_1386'], 'auditor_C': ['EMP_4332', 'EMP_4268', 'EMP_1874'], 'auditor_D': ['EMP_3584', 'EMP_1969', 'EMP_3999']}
​
```